# geopandas difference only if a column's value is greater

Tags: python, geometry, polygon, geopandas, shapely

Initialize data:

```
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon

geoms = gpd.GeoSeries([
    Polygon([(0, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2), (0, 2)]),
    Polygon([(1, 1), (3, 1), (3, 3), (1, 3)]),
    Polygon([(0, 0), (3, 0), (3, 3), (0, 3)]),
])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geoms)
gdf["value"] = [3, 2, 1]

gdf.plot(cmap='tab10', alpha=0.5)
```

[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhQw5.png)

Then I want to make holes into the polygons where `value`s are greater than the current row.

```
gdf_list = []
for value in gdf["value"]:
    gdf_equal_value = gdf.loc[gdf["value"] == value, "geometry"]
    gdf_above_value = gdf.loc[gdf["value"] > value, "geometry"]
    gdf_list.append(
        (value, gdf_equal_value.difference(gdf_above_value.unary_union))
    )


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for value, geom in gdf_list:
    geom.plot()
    plt.xlim(0, 3)
    plt.ylim(0, 3)
    plt.title(value)
```

[holes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsZch.png)

Since I have much more unique values in my actual dataset, is there a way to optimize this (e.g. not have to loop through each one)?

Comment: It's not very clear to me what you want your end result to be. One suggestion would be to use the `unique` function in a couple of places. You can also think about doing a `dissolve` after a clever reclassification. I'll try to expand in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in my comment, I'm not 100% sure I understand what you want your final product to look like. Please consider editing your question to make that clearer.

In your original question, your final product was a list of `(value, geodataframe)` pairs, and the `geodataframe` contained the rows of the original `gdf` differenced with respect to a dissolved polygon of the `gdf` elements whose values were larger than the reference value.

Is that exactly what you want?

Here's a quick solution to get to something similar, but not exactly identical.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

geoms = gpd.GeoSeries([
    Polygon([(0, 0), (2, 0), (2, 2), (0, 2)]),
    Polygon([(1, 1), (3, 1), (3, 3), (1, 3)]),
    Polygon([(0, 0), (3, 0), (3, 3), (0, 3)]),
])
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=geoms)
gdf["value"] = [3, 2, 1]


gdf_list = []
for value in gdf["value"].unique():
    gdf['classif'] = np.select(
        condlist=[(gdf['value'] == value), (gdf['value'] > value)], 
        choicelist=['Equal','Larger'], 
        default=np.nan)
    
    gdf_diss = gdf.dissolve(by='classif',dropna=True).reset_index()
    
    if gdf_diss['classif'].isin(['Equal','Larger']).sum() == 2:
        gdf_list.append(
            (value, gdf_diss.iloc[0]['geometry'].difference(gdf_diss.iloc[1]['geometry']))
    )
```

In this case, the `gdf_list` contains `(value,Polygon)` pairs. The `Polygon`s are the result of the difference between two other polygons:

- A) The dissolved polygon of all the rows that have a value in the `value` column that is **equal** to the reference value.
- B) The dissolved polygon of all the rows that have a value in the `value` column that is **larger** to the reference value.

Note that the result isn't a `GeoDataFrame` of the differences - for each value, it's a single `Polygon`.

While this might not be exactly what you were looking for, I hope the tricks I used (dissolving instead of subsetting) might help what you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this method seems slower than my original method, but I learned something new with np.select!